# Run shell script without close the previous process

Tags: shell

I got stuck in this problem. I need to run two commands in shell script, but they can't stop each other.

For example, this shell script:

```
psql database user &
gedit file
```

If I run these commands up, only the gedit process stays open and I can't see where the process of psql is.

But if I do this:

```
gedit file &
psql database user
```

I can see the psql's process, but it's closed by messages of gedit's process.

How can I execute this script without one process close the other?

Comment: Run them both in the background and redirect the output, if any? I'm not sure at the moment (because I cannot remember), but you should be able to run your `psql` command in a separate shell instance (for lack of a better word at this time). Read up on some bash stuff and you'll probably come across it.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge, I think the word you're looking for is "subshell" -- but `psql` is an interactive process; without being passed a script to execute or piped content to run on stdin (neither of which the OP is doing here), it only makes sense in the foreground. And putting it into a subshell... well, one could do that, but in the immediate situation I can't quite see the point.

Comment: I used the psql process just as an example, because I believe many people know him. The process that I need is not interactive, but needs to stay open as psql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to suppress output from `gedit`:

```
gedit file >/dev/null 2>&1 &
psql database user
```

---

However, the claim:

> I can see the psql's process, but it's closed by messages of gedit's process.

...simply doesn't happen: Messages from `gedit` go directly to the terminal; `psql` can't see them, so it can't possibly be exiting because of them.

Comment: By "closed by messages of gedit's process" I'm guessing the OP means that gedit spews to the terminal and overwrites the `psql` prompt and the OP thinks that means `psql` is gone.

Comment: ...except that this represents a misunderstanding, since it _isn't_ gone -- anything they type is still going to `psql`.

Comment: Agreed. Just pointing out the confusion I think they had since I don't think they meant it was exiting (they do say they see the `psql` process after all) because I thought directly addressing that confusion is likely to be more helpful to them then your (entirely correct) assertion that something they probably didn't mean isn't happening is by itself.